# How to display partial only on a page and its subpages? OctoberCMS

Tags: if-statement, octobercms

Hello!

How to display partial only on a page and its subpages? How to build a condition correctly?

how to display the menu on "about company" and its subpages

.../about-company

.../about-company/history

.../about-company/something-else
 
 I know what can be done to the condition for one page

```
if this.page.id
```

and how to do for all subsequent subpages –

Comment: can you elaborate little more with any example etc.. so we can help you better

Comment: how to display the menu on "about company" and its subpages

.../about-company
.../about-company/history
.../about-company/something-else

I know what can be done to the condition
`if this.page.id`
and how to do for all subsequent subpages

Comment: How about just creating multiple layouts. About Layout, Price Layout, Blog Layout. Then all of your About Pages uses the About Layout with the About Components and so forth. Done.

Comment: I want to make not several identical layouts, which differ only in the presence of a menu or text, and one with a condition. 
I do not know how to specify that it is necessary to display this element on the page and its subpages. by inDir or subcategory do not make a selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically do this using layouts like **Pettis Brandon** suggested in the comments.

You seem to be under the impression that this would require duplicate code. It does not. You would place any duplicate code (code that remains the same in multiple Layouts) in partials. Different Layouts would simply include the same partials.